# Difference between "global" and "import __main__"

Tags: python

I defined three functions that should change a global variable `x`.

```
def changeXto1():
    global x
    x = 1

def changeXto2():
    from __main__ import x
    x = 2

def changeXto3():
    import __main__
    __main__.x = 3

x = 0
print x
changeXto1()
print x
changeXto2()
print x
changeXto3()
print x
```

It gives the result:

```
0
1
1
3
```

`changeXto1` uses the normal global statement. The result is as expected `x` == 1. `changeXto2` uses `from __main__ import` to address `x`. This doesn't work. Afterwards `x` is still 1. `changeXto3` uses `import main` to address `x` via `__main__.x`. The result afterwards is 3 as expected.

Why doesn't `from __main__ import` work in `changeXto2`, while `import __main__` is working in `changeXto3`? Why do we need a global statement in Python if we can address global variables also with the `__main__` module?

Comment: changeXto2 only sets a local variable: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/

Comment: I do not see anything about importing modulesimporting there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is related to how Python translate your code to bytecode (the compilation step).

When compiling a function, Python treat all variable that are assigned as local variable and perform an optimisation to reduce the number of name lookup it would have to do. Each local variable get assigned an index, and when the function is called their value will be stored in a stack local array addressed by index. The compiler will emit `LOAD_FAST` and `STORE_FAST` opcode to access the variable.

The `global` syntax indicate instead to the compiler that even if the variable is assigned a value, it should not be considered a local variable, should not be assigned an index. It will instead use `LOAD_GLOBAL` and `STORE_GLOBAL` opcode to access the variable. Those opcode are slower since they use the name to do a lookup in possibly many dictionaries (locals, globals).

If a variable is only accessed for reading the value, the compiler always emit `LOAD_GLOBAL` since it don't know whether it is supposed to be a local or global variable, and thus assume it is a global.

So, in your first function, using `global x` informs the compiler that you want it to treat the write access to `x` as writing to a global variable instead of a local variable. The opcodes for the function make it clear:

```
>>> dis.dis(changeXto1)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              3 STORE_GLOBAL             0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

In your third example, you import the `__main__` module into a local variable named `__main__` and then assign to its `x` field. Since module are object that store all top-level mapping as fields, you are assigning to the variable `x` in the `__main__` module. And as you found, the `__main__` module fields directly map to the values in the `globals()` dictionary because your code is defined in the `__main__` module. The opcodes show that you don't access `x` directly:

```
>>> dis.dis(changeXto3)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (__main__)
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (__main__)

  3          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (__main__)
             18 STORE_ATTR               1 (x)
             21 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE
```

The second example is interesting. Since you assign a value to the `x` variable, the compiler assume it is a local variable and does the optimisation. Then, the `from __main__ import x` does import the module `__main__` and create a new binding the value of `x` in the module `__main__` to the local variable named `x`. This is always the case, `from ${module} import ${name}` just create a new binding the current namespace. When you assign a new value to the variable `x` you just change the current binding, not the binding in module `__main__` that is unrelated (though if the value is mutable, and you mutate it, the change will be visible through all the bindings). Here are the opcodes:

```
>>> dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('x',))
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (__main__)
              9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (x)
             12 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             15 POP_TOP             

  3          16 LOAD_CONST               3 (2)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

A good way to think about this is that in Python all assignment are binding a name to a value in a dictionary, and dereference is just doing a dictionary lookup (this is a rough approximation, but pretty close to the conceptual model). When doing `obj.field`, then you are looking up the hidden dictionary of `obj` (accessible via `obj.__dict__`) for the `"field"` key.

When you have a naked variable name, then it is looked up in the `locals()` dictionary, then the `globals()` dictionary if it is different (they are the same when the code is executed at a module level). For an assignment, it always put the binding in the `locals()` dictionary, unless you declared that you wanted a global access by doing `global ${name}` (this syntax also works at top-level).

So translating your function, this is almost if you had written:

```
# NOTE: this is valid Python code, but is less optimal than
# the original code. It is here only for demonstration.

def changeXto1():
    globals()['x'] = 1

def changeXto2():
    locals()['x'] = __import__('__main__').__dict__['x']
    locals()['x'] = 2

def changeXto3():
    locals()['__main__'] = __import__('__main__')
    locals()['__main__'].__dict__['x'] = 3
```

Comment: Thank you for that very comprehensive answer. I always thought `import module` and `from module import` are the same except that the variables are called differently. I see that there is a difference, when the new variable is created using `from import`. The variable in the original module keeps the same, but the variable in the local namespace is newly created and bound to the local name.

Answer (score 8):

> Why doesn't `from __main__ import` work in `changeXto2`, while `import __main__` is working in `changeXto3`?

It works fine, it just doesn't do what you want. It copies the name and value into the local namespace instead of having the code access `__main__`'s namespace.

> Why do we need a global statement in Python if we can address global variables also with the `__main__` module?

Because they only do the same thing *when your code is running in `__main__`*. If you're running in, say, `othermodule` after importing it, then `__main__` will refer to the main script and *not* `othermodule`.