# Python:How to import a object in a module to local reference?

Tags: python

I'm loading a object from pickle, which depend on some other. And in order to sort them, I put them in a module.
The problem is, for example there is a object `foo` in module `set.py`, when importing it will become `<class 'set.foo'>` instead of `<class 'foo'>`, so the object loading from pickle cannot find the dependence.

I have tried:
`import set`
`from set import foo` / `from set import *`
`from set import foo as foo`
and print it to see the the reference
but it still import as `<class 'set.foo'>`

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that people can run to reproduce your problem. Instead of describing what your code does, it's so much more helpful to include it in your question. Please also take the [tour], and read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using:

```
locals()['foo'] = __import__('set').__dict__['foo']
```

refer to [Difference between "global" and "import __main__"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14909285/difference-between-global-and-import-main)

It create a binding of `foo` in module `set` to local variable, so the object loading from pickle can find the dependence in `__main__`.

Answer (score -1):

i guess it's telling your file name then the class name. Your file name *'set.py'* and you are importing '*foo*' class.so it tells you the **foo** obj is from file set and its foo class <class 'set.foo'> .

if you want to get  you should move the class within your current file.

Comment: Yes, I have tried put it in the same file before, and it did work. In that case, there will be a lot of class needed to be imported in a single file, which made it quit difficult to maintain. Therefor, I really want to detach them.

Comment: so that's it! I don't think theres a way of geting the class (<class foo>) without the file name(<class set.foo>) in python.